# Parameter is not passing to crystal report in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have parametrized store procedure as source for Crystal Report. I am trying to pass them from behind Code C#.

I referred many topics, but still missing something, and getting error :

`Failed to open a rowset.` 
 `Details:`
 `ADO Error Code: 0x`
  `Source: Microsoft SQL Native Client`
  `Description: Procedure 'SP_GetProductsbySales' expects parameter '@top', which was not   supplied.` 
  `SQL State: 42000`
  `Native Error: Failed to open a rowset.`
  `Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\TopSelling_Report {B8B4EAE6-D01E-4D18-9003-23A047F9DD5B}.rpt: Failed to open a rowset`

Here is my code :

```
 private void ConfigureCrystalReports()
{
    rpt = new ReportDocument();

    string reportPath = Server.MapPath("TopSelling_Report.rpt");

    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo.Clear();
    ParameterFields param = CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo;
    ParameterField top = new ParameterField();
    top.Name = "@top";
    ParameterDiscreteValue top_val = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    top_val.Value = 100;
    top.CurrentValues.Add(top_val);

    ParameterField all = new ParameterField();
    all.Name = "@all";
    ParameterDiscreteValue all_val = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    all_val.Value = false;
    all.CurrentValues.Add(all_val);

    param.Add(top);
    param.Add(all);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = param;


    rpt.Load(reportPath);
    rpt.SetParameterValue(0, Convert.ToInt32(50));
    rpt.SetParameterValue(1, Convert.ToBoolean(false));


    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    connectionInfo.ServerName = "xxxx";
    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "xxxxx";
    connectionInfo.UserID = "xxx";
    connectionInfo.Password = "xxxx";
    SetDBLogonForReport(connectionInfo, rpt);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
}
private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ReportDocument reportDocument)
{
    Tables tables = reportDocument.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
        tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
    }
}
```

I tried to pass parameters in both ways as you can see, but still getting error.
I found particular issue, if I remove **SetDBLogonForReport()** method, then it is working fine. So, if I remove auto login, then it is working fine but if I keep it as it is or modify code for that one , then it 'll give be above Error.

I try to replace my code with SetDatabaseLogon() method, but still it is giving me Login Prompt which is not expected.

I am using visual studio 2005.
Appreciate for your help.
Thanks.

Comment: @Hakoo_desai please check this [www.codeproject.com link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10173/Loading-Crystal-Report-reports-which-use-Stored-Pr)

Comment: @Hiten004 I had already looked that one. I tried in that manner as well as new method. `rpt.SetParameterValue(0, Convert.ToInt32(50)); rpt.SetParameterValue(1, Convert.ToBoolean(false));` All these are working only if I **remove mehtod for  Autologin ** i.e. `private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ReportDocument reportDocument)`.